# Почему на устройствах apple криво работает свойство transform?

Tags: html, css, apple, transform

Сделал на css3 эффект переворачивающихся карточек при наведении на них. Вот сайт на котором это реализовано https://webinar.ablethink.ru  Проблема в том, что на устройствах apple(проблема была замечена на iphone, macbook и ipad mini, возможно и на других устройствах apple так же будет) эти карточки отображаются криво(см. скрин) и я не могу понять в чем дело и как это исправить, что я не так сделал?
[image: скриншот с iphone6]

Comment: Надо добавить `-webkit-`, он отвечает за отображение в некоторых браузерах

Answer (score 0):

У вас в css-стилях указано только свойство `transform`, используйте дополнительный вариант с префиксом `-webkit-`. Например, вот так:

```
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
transform: rotateY(-180deg);
```

Браузер Safari до версии 9.2 не поддерживает это свойство без префикса:

```
http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d
```

Comment: Не помогло. Safari версии 10+